# How do I make the right conditions for the url based on the value of a variable? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, conditional-statements

My script javascript like this :

```
<script>

    var url = 'http://my-app.test/item';
    var sessionBrand = 'honda';
    var sessionModel = 'jazz';
    var sessionCategory = 'velg';
    var sessionKeyword = 'RS 175/60 R 15';

    if(sessionBrand)
        var brand = '?brand='+sessionBrand;
    else
        var brand = '';

    if(sessionModel)
        var model = '&model='+sessionModel;
    else
        var model = '';

    if(sessionCategory)
        var category = '&category='+sessionCategory;
    else
        var category = '';

    if(sessionKeyword)
        var keyword = '&keyword='+this.sessionKeyword;
    else
        var keyword = '';

    var newUrl = url+brand+model+category+keyword;
    console.log(newUrl);

</script>
```

The result of console.log like this :

```
http://my-app.test/item?brand=honda&model=jazz&category=velg&keyword=RS 175/60 R 15
```

var sessionBrand, sessionModel, sessionCategory and sessionKeyword is dynamic. It can change.  It can be null or it can have value

I have a problem

For example the case like this :

```
    var sessionBrand = '';
    var sessionModel = '';
    var sessionCategory = '';
    var sessionKeyword = 'RS 175/60 R 15';
```

The url to be like this :

```
http://my-app.test/item&keyword=RS 175/60 R 15
```

Should the url like this :

```
http://my-app.test/item?keyword=RS 175/60 R 15
```

I'm still confused to make the condition

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the array for params and then join them with `&` separator. For example:

```
var url = 'http://my-app.test/item';
var sessionBrand = 'honda';
var sessionModel = 'jazz';
var sessionCategory = 'velg';
var sessionKeyword = 'RS 175/60 R 15';

var params = [];

if (sessionBrand) {
    params.push('brand=' + sessionBrand);
}

if (sessionModel) {
    params.push('model=' + sessionModel);
}

if(sessionCategory) {
    params.push('category=' + sessionCategory);
}

if(sessionKeyword) {
    params.push('category=' + sessionCategory);
}
var newUrl = url + '?' + params.join('&');
console.log(newUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it is prefacing all query parameters with a `&` - except for the `sessionBrand`. What you need in a URL is for the *first* parameter to start with a `?`, and all others with a `&`. As you saw, your code doesn't do this when there is no `sessionBrand`.

There are number of ways to fix this. Probably the neatest I can think of is to assemble the various parts as you are, but *without* any prefixes - then join them all together at the end. Like this (I just saw Viktor's solution, it's exactly the same idea, but neater because he rewrote more of your earlier code):

```
if(sessionBrand)
    var brand = 'brand='+sessionBrand;
else
    var brand = '';

if(sessionModel)
    var model = 'model='+sessionModel;
else
    var model = '';

if(sessionCategory)
    var category = 'category='+sessionCategory;
else
    var category = '';

if(sessionKeyword)
    var keyword = 'keyword='+this.sessionKeyword;
else
    var keyword = '';

var queryString = '?' + [sessionBrand, sessionModel, sessionCategory, sessionKeyword].filter(function(str) {
    return str.length > 0;
}).join("&");

var newUrl = url+queryString;
```